# После использования функции формы на аяксе перестают работать

Tags: ajax, javascript, php

```
function nextPhoto() {  
        jQuery.ajax({url: "/guess_the_group/workphoto.php",
            dataType: "html",
            type: "GET",
            success: function(msg) {
                //alert("");
                document.getElementById('photoband').innerHTML = msg;
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Ошибка');
            }
        }); 
    }

$(document).ready(function ()
{ 
    $("#PhotoForm").submit(function ()
    {
        var str = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "/guess_the_group/guess_group.php",
            data: str,
            success: function (msg)
            {
                $("#note").ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings)
                {
                    if (msg == 'OK') // Если сообщение отправлено, поблагодарим пользователя
                    {
                        result = '<div id="notification_ok">Угадал, наглый :)</div>';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = msg;
                    }
                    $(this).html(result);
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Формой отправляю данные в пхп скрипт, и получаю ответ, если ответ правильный - одно действие, если нет - другое.
Когда нажимаю на кнопку nextphoto, форма на аяксе перестает работать. Тупо открывается пхп с результатом ответа. В чем может быть дело?

UPD:
А вот еще вопрос, я сделал, чтобы если ответ правильный, кнопка отправить убиралась.

```
result = 'Угадал, наглый хорек :)'; $("#otp").hide('slow');
```

Но теперь, когда щелкаешь `nextPhoto`, кнопка все еще убирается. Хотя ответа еще небыло.

Comment: Попробуй открыть в Мазилле и посмотреть в консоль ошибок может у тебя в JavaScripts ошибки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function ajax_submit(){
    var str = $("#PhotoForm").serialize();
    $.ajax(
    {
          type: "POST",
          url: "/guess_the_group/guess_group.php",
          data: str,
          success: function (msg)
          {
             $("#note").ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings)
          {
             if (msg == 'OK') // Если сообщение отправлено, поблагодарим пользователя
                 {
                     result = '<div id="notification_ok">Угадал, наглый :)</div>';
                 } else {
                     result = msg;
                 }
                 $(this).html(result);
          });
         }
    });
}
```

Comment: Сделал кнопку вида <input type="button" onclick="ajax_submit()">
Начало функции 
    $("#PhotoForm").submit(function ()
    {
        var str = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax(
        {

Конец функции
        });
        return false;
    });

Все верно? Кнопка не кликабельна стала

Comment: Исправил свой ответ. Кнопка - правильно. А вот Функция должна быть как я написал в ответе.

Вам нужно понять сам смысл. Раз вы убрали кнопку SUBMIT, то и отправки формы не будет, значит обрабатывать событие отправки не нужно. Мы создали кнопку типа BUTTON и обрабатываем уже событие click по ней

Comment: Благодарю, помогли :)

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Трудно что-то сказать, отредактируйте ваш код в вопросе так, как оно есть сейчас, тогда попробуем разобраться

Answer (score 0):

Два решения:

1. return false; нужно возвращать не в коллбэке аякса, а в колбэке submit
2. Кнопку формы делать не submit а button и обрабатывать ее событием click

Comment: 1. Перестало вообще работать.
2. Ничего не изменилось.